# Integrating $\frac{1}{(1-7x^{2})^{2}}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

How do I integrate the following algebraic function?

$$\int \frac{1}{(1-7x^{2})^{2}} \,  {\rm d} x$$

Really , without use of hyperbolic function , can it be done ... Actually , my syllabus doesn't allow using hyperbolic functions ...

Comment: Decompose in simple fractions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Let

$$I:=\int\frac{dx}{1-x^2}=\text{artanh }x,\\
J:=\int\frac{dx}{(1-x^2)^2}$$

and notice that$^*$

$$\left(\frac x{1-x^2}\right)'=\frac{1+x^2}{(1-x^2)^2}=\frac{2-(1-x^2)}{(1-x^2)^2}$$ so that

$$2J-I=\frac x{1-x^2}.$$

This yields

$$2J=\frac x{1-x^2}-\text{artanh }x.$$

I let you do the easy adjustments to deal with the coefficient $7$.

---

$^*$This trick is discovered by observing that the square at the denominator might come from the derivative of $\dfrac{P(x)}{1-x^2}$. If we are lucky, we can find a polynomial $P(x)$ such that the derivative will be of the form $\dfrac{ax^2+bx+c}{(1-x^2)^2}$, because this can be written $A+\dfrac B{1-x^2}+\dfrac{Cx}{1-x^2}$ where all terms are easy to integrate.

Trying $P(x)=1$ and $P(x)=x$ leads us to the solution.

Comment: @YvesDaoust...Can you tell me what does prime(') mean here...And what is the name of the method...?How do you do that?I've learnt only about partial and substitution...

Comment: arctanh x is yielded from 1/1+x²...?

Comment: @NehalSamee: this is an ad-hoc method, which relies only on *decomposition*. The prime is the derivative. Check a table of hyperbolic functions.

Comment: @YvesDaoust...What is prime (`) here...?

Comment: @YvesDaoust...I've understood ...That's derivative...Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int\frac{1}{(1-7x^2)^2}dx =\int x^{-1}\cdot \frac{x}{(1-7x^2)^2}dx$$

Using Integration by  parts method

$$I=\frac{1}{14}\cdot \frac{1}{x(1-7x^2)}-\frac{1}{14}\int\frac{1}{x^2(1-7x^2)}dx$$

$$I=\frac{1}{14}\cdot \frac{1}{x(1-7x^2)}-\frac{1}{14}\int\bigg[\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{1-7x^2}\bigg]dx$$

$$I=\frac{1}{14}\cdot \frac{1}{x(1-7x^2)}+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{7}}\ln\bigg|\frac{1+\sqrt{7}x}{1+\sqrt{7}x}\bigg|+\mathcal{C}$$

Comment: @DurgeshTiwari...By integration by parts , you mean ∫uv dx ... or ∫v du...?

Comment: Yes nehal. $$\int u\cdot v \;dx = u\cdot \int vdx-\int \bigg(u'\cdot \int vdx\bigg)dx$$

Answer (score -3):

Hint:
$$\int\frac{1}{49x^4-14x^2+1}dt={1\over2}\int\frac{2\over x^2}{(7x)^2+{1\over x^2}-14}$$

Now try completing the square and substitution

Comment: Why the down votes? Integration can be easily done like this if hyperbolic function not allowed. Would you like me to it here?